# How can I read specific data from XML or Text files?

Tags: c#

I want to store user data in a XML or text file. I know how to write data into a file, the problem I have is reading that data and getting what I want out of it.

I want to store a MySQL connection string with my own custom data. For example...

```
 "Name=Localhost;CoreVerr=5.x;Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Uid=root;Password=root;Database=accounts;"
```

*Note that the custom data is "Name" and "CoreVerr" as these are not found in a normal MySQL connection string.*

Now I want to read data from "Name" and "CoreVerr". So the output would then be, 'Localhost', '5.x'. How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: After reading the string from your XML file you could split it by the ';' character and use a regex like @"\w+=(\w+)" to find the key and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XmlDocument class to do this in C#. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This allows you to target specific nodes and attributes within your XML document once you have loaded it and extract the information required.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [application and user settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx).

Settings allow you to specify configuration values in setting files and provide easy access.